# It's Sun., Correct CPU Time. PHP in local host displays Mon

Tags: php, date, localhost

Below is the code, time, and browser in an picture. The computer time is Sunday 5/17/2020 and has the correct timezone. XAMPP has the correct time as well. In the code,

```
$dayofweek = date("w"); 
switch (dayofweek) { case 0: echo "Sun.";}
```

For what reason could it be displaying Monday?

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't share the picture, but the description says it clearly.

Comment: What does `echo date('c');` output?

Comment: 2020-05-18T02:43:08+02:00

Comment: There you go. Wherever your PHP is running it is Monday.

Comment: looks like my browsers time is totally off... My cpu time is correct, and so is xampp... I cant find any info on changing my browsers time.

Comment: Browsers don't have time and PHP is executed on the server, not in your browser.

Comment: Hard to say because there appears to be code missing, given the `switch` without any others and the missing `break;`. Edit: Seeing `switch (dayofweek)` to me, isn't actual code. That is missing the `$` sign for it and would have triggered an undefined constant notice.

Comment: Someone gave an answer below, did you try it? Did it solve this? Question's unclear in too many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change timezone in XAMPP: httpd.conf (\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) 
Add this code if it not exist:

```
SetEnv TZ Europe/Athens
```

PHP Config: php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini) 
Edit this line:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Athens"
```

Reset Xampp control panel and here you go, this made me headache before

Comment: Huy knew exactly what I meant and where I should go. The problem was the time was incorrect in the server as John had mentioned. Going to the php.ini file and switching the timezone was the answer! Yes, it was a headache to find that tiny bit of code. Thank goodness for searches!